# IDA pro 7... how do you tell which module each string is in?

Tags: ida

In IDA pro 7, when you generate the list of stirngs in the strings window, it gives you an "address" which starts with something like "debug12x"... is there any way to tell which module that is in? Or what binary file's were involved in creating that? The debug12xxxxx address isn't something I understand, but I'm trying to find which module or binary file had the code that created that string... but when I double click the string it takes me to the "IDA-View RIP" which says the exact same debug12xxxxx and doesn't seem to say anywhere more about where the string came from or which module made it...? This is happening when attaching a debugger to a running process in windows 10.

Comment: Is this from a process dump or dynamic analysis?  Or is static analysis?